# Checking all checkboxes and cloning them to another table when i click a checkall checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

Here is what i'm trying to achieve, I want to clone all the checked row of a checkbox when the checkall checkbox is checked and when it unchecks it unchecks the rest of the checkboxes too and remove them from the cloned table

Below is my Jquery Code

```
var $checky = $("input[type=checkbox].checky");

  $("input:checkbox#checked").click(function(){
      $checky.prop('checked',true);
      $('#selection-form tbody tr').clone().appendTo("#tbl2 tbody");
      calculateTotal();
  })
  $checky.click(function() {
    //calculateTotal();
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      calculateTotal();
      $(this).closest("tr").clone().appendTo("#tbl2 tbody");
    } else {
      var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-index");
      var findRow = $("#tbl2 tr[data-index='" + index + "']");
      calculateTotal();
      findRow.remove();
    }
  });
```

I tried that but it is only cloning the table header and it calculates the total,
All i want is for it to clone the rest of the table data rows

Comment: A working demo might entice more people to look into your issue

Comment: ok i'll add a working demo

Comment: Here is a working demo http://jsbin.com/cugazuxuqe/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector for the table is wrong since you have no `#selection-form` in your DOM, you can try

```
$('#tb1 tbody tr').clone().appendTo("#tbl2 tbody");
```

EDIT

I changed the code to use the change events instead of the click events and let the individual check boxes handle the cloning and calculations.

```js
var $checky = $("input[type=checkbox].checky");

$("input:checkbox#checked").change(function(){
  var filter;
  if (this.checked)
    filter = ':not(:checked)';
  else
    filter = ':checked';
  $checky.filter(filter).prop('checked',this.checked).trigger('change');
    
  //$('#tb1 tbody tr').clone().append("#tbl2 tbody");
  //calculateTotal();
})
$checky.change(function() {
  //calculateTotal();
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    calculateTotal();
    $(this).closest("tr").clone().appendTo("#tbl2 tbody");
  } else {
    var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-index");
    var findRow = $("#tbl2 tr[data-index='" + index + "']");
    calculateTotal();
    findRow.remove();
  }
});

function calculateTotal() {
  //if($(this).is(":checked")) {
  var total = 0;

  $checky.filter(":checked").each(function() {
    total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat($(this).attr('data-amount'));
    if(total !== 0) {
      $("#data2").show();
    }else {
      $("#data2").hide();
    }
  });
  $("#total").val(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <table class="table table-hover" id="tb1">
    <thead style="background-color: rgb(25, 96, 143); color: #fff;" id="feesTbl">
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="checked"/></th>
        <th>Fee Name</th>
        <th>Fee Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr data-index="1">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checky" name="feeids[]" value="1" data-amount="2000">
        </td>
        <td>
           Test Data 1
        </td>
        <td>
          2000
        </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr data-index="2">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checky" name="feeids[]" value="2" data-amount="3000">
        </td>
        <td>
           Test Data 2
        </td>
        <td>
          3000
        </td>
      </tr>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <table id="tbl2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Fee Description</th>
        <th>Fee Amount</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

    </tbody>

  </table>
  <div id="showTotal">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      Total
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <input type="text" id="total" name="total" class="form-control" style="outline: none; border: 0;" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not working i tried it, its only calculating for the total, but not appending all to the second table, i've edited the jsbin file

Comment: The id is `tb1` tee bee one not `tbl`

Comment: You changed `appendTo` to `append`, it should be `appendTo`

Comment: Now its working but its not removing them when i uncheck the checkbox